# Android рестарт фрагмента

Tags: android, android-fragment

подскажите пожалуйста решение, как можно сделать рестарт фрагмента, обнулив данные содержащие в переменных.

Answer (score 0):

Скорее вам стоит ответить, для чего вам это нужно, потому как скорее всего вы что-то делаете неправильно, раз вам нужно такое поведение.

А вообще можно внутри хостовой активити вы можете заменить фрагмент методом replace().

```
getSupportFragmentManager(
            .beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.container, YourFragment.newInstance())
            .commit();
```

Comment: Я использую javamail api, вызываю камеру делаю снимок и сохраняю адрес снимка в строковую переменную, и передаю снимок по почте, проблема том что при повторной отправки письма без снимка он прикрепляет это фото повторно, меня интересовало как можно сделать рестарт фрагмента что бы вернуть его в исходное состояние.

Comment: Ну так а зачем вам перезагружать фрагмент? Вам просто нужно занулять переменную. Или описать какую-то логику, чтоб ваш снимок отправлялся только 1 раз. Перезагрзука фрагмента это точно не то что вам нужно